# POST with multipart/form-data using node.js supertest

Tags: node.js, rest, testing, supertest

I was trying to use the Node.js supertest to test some REST API.

```
request(app)
      .post("/products")
      .set(
        "Authorization",
        "Bearer my jwt token here"
      )
      .set("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
      .field("name", "Tomato")
      .field("userId", "5d921d306e96d70a28989127")
      .attach(
        "productImage",
        "D:/NodeJS/node-rest-shop/uploads/1558612339690managing-redis.jpg"
      )
      .expect(201)
      .then(res => {
        const body = res.body;
        expect(body).to.contain.property("message");
        expect(body).to.contain.property("productId");
        expect(body).to.contain.property("date");
        expect(body).to.contain.property("user");
        expect(body).to.contain.property("request");
        done();
      })
      .catch(err => done(err));
```

> .field("userId", **userId**)

Is there any way to set the value of **userId** as a variable without setting a hardcoded string value? It is a MongoDB object id.

When I'm using value as a variable this error occurred.

```
TypeError: source.on is not a function
    at Function.DelayedStream.create (node_modules\delayed-stream\lib\delayed_stream.js:33:10)
    at FormData.CombinedStream.append (node_modules\combined-stream\lib\combined_stream.js:45:37)
    at FormData.append (node_modules\form-data\lib\form_data.js:74:3)
    at Test.RequestBase.field (node_modules\superagent\lib\request-base.js:406:23)
    at Context.done (test\api\product\product.js:77:8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can interpret this as 2 different ways, so I'll just answer both:

> Can the value be specified as a non-string, e.g. a number.

`multipart/form-data` doesn't really have any sort of typing. Everything will be interpreted as a string usually. Your controller will need to do any conversion.

> Can I use a variable in place of a hardcoded string.

Yes, you can.

Instead of:

```
.field("userId", "5d921d306e96d70a28989127")
```

You can just use:

```
.field("userId", userId)
```

As long as you defined a userId variable earlier

Comment: When I'm using,  `.field("userId", userId)` this error occured  `TypeError: source.on is not a function
      at Function.DelayedStream.create (node_modules\delayed-stream\lib\delayed_stream.js:33:10)
      at FormData.CombinedStream.append (node_modules\combined-stream\lib\combined_stream.js:45:37)
      at FormData.append (node_modules\form-data\lib\form_data.js:74:3)
      at Test.RequestBase.field (node_modules\superagent\lib\request-base.js:406:23)
      at Context.done (test\api\product\product.js:77:8)`

Comment: What does `userId` contain?

Comment: `usrId: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId()`

Comment: `new mongoose.Types.ObjectId()` seems like it's an object. Maybe the object has a `toString()` method?

Comment: this is a node.js project. As the https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/ states: An ObjectId must be a single string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters.

Comment: Yes, but `new mongoose.Types.ObjectId()` does not return a string, it returns an object. You need to convert it to a string.

Answer (score 0):

userId is a `new mongoose.Types.ObjectId()`. So, it does not return a string, it returns an object. You need to convert it to a string. 
We can use this.
`.field("userId", String(userId))`